# AADSTS90027 We are unable to issue tokens from this API version on the MSA tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-api

We are using OAuth2 to get tokens to access the Sharepoint API (.../_api/web/ etc). We have two app registrations set up. Everything has been working fine until the last few days when we have started seeing the following error during the first part of the OAuth flow:

AADSTS90027 'We are unable to issue tokens from this API version on the MSA tenant. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this'.

**This only happens for one of the app registrations** and it **only happens for prompt=consent**. If we use **prompt=select_account** it works fine.

The app registrations are identical (by inspecting manifests) apart from IDs and naming. Both app registrations have these settings:

```
...

"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,

...

"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
```

It seems odd that this issue only happens for one of the app registrations - perhaps Microsoft are rolling out mandatory upgrades gradually? There is no mention of this particular error here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes

If we have to 'use version 2.0 of the protocol' which I assume means this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent it's not clear to us whether this is compatible with the Sharepoint API. We have tried v2.0 and can successfully get a token, but currently getting 'Invalid issuer or signature' when trying to use the token with the Sharepoint API.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

**UPDATE:**

- just to provide some form of closure, we ended up upgrading to version 2.0
- the token *is* compatible with the Sharepoint API (IIRC we had an issue relating to scopes as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow - the important part was 'For the /authorize leg of the request, this can cover multiple resources')

Comment: Are you using a personal Microsoft account? Usually this error occurs when using a personal Microsoft account. But your app registration has `"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs"`, which means it doesn't support personal Microsoft account. Can you check and provide more details?

Comment: No, tested with two (separate organisations) AAD administered accounts. This was previously working for well over a year BTW.

Comment: The two accounts are both work accounts, not guest accounts?

Comment: Correct they are not guest accounts